# can we send modelAttribute from one war to other war using SpringMVC RESTful API?

Tags: modelattribute

Suppose I have a JSP in one WAR which is calling a RESTful Spring MVC controller which is located in another WAR.

I want to transfer a complete model object(which is for the jsp component) and not one by one jsp component values using such as @RequestParam or @PathParam.

Can I send modelAttribute from one war to other war using SpringMVC RESTful API? so that I don't need to use @RequestParam or @PathParam etc for each variable?

Comment: E.g, Code will be such as
ONE.war
 myjsp.jsp
  <form:form action="" modelAttribute="employee" ...>

ANOTHER.war
 MyRestfulSpringController.java
  public void save(@ModelAttribute("employee") ...)

Comment: we know we can bind and transfer a model object for jsp components to restful spring mvc controller but here both jsp and controller are in same war. WHAT IF I HAVE TWO WARs one for jsp and other for restful spring mvc controller?

Comment: Can i able still to transfer model object from one war to other war using same modelAttribute or in this case we need other features/annotation such as RequestParam or PathParam etc and send jsp components values one by one to restful spring mvc controller?